# Almacenar la contraseña del usuario en sesiones

Tags: php, seguridad

Quiero usar la librería Sodium para cifrar el contenido de ciertos campos en una base de datos. Como clave quiero usar la clave del usuario. Solo se me ocurren 2 métodos:

- Guardar la contraseña plana en una sesión (no me gusta esta solución)
- La contraseña cifrada con un hash. Lo que tiene sus propios problemas.

¿Alguien ha tenido que solucionar algo así?

Comment: Creo que todos nos hemos enfrentado a eso. Podría serte de utilidad: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798275/best-way-to-store-passwords-in-mysql-database y https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security.html (si por el momento trabajas con mysql)

Comment: Si el usuario está autenticado en tu backend puedes guardar la clave de cifrado en la sesión del usuario y no en el browser. Otra alternativa -si no vas a usar la sesión de PHP- es implementar JSON Web Tokens (JWT) de manera que el usuario una vez tenga el JWT en su browser lo envíe como header `Authorization`. Del lado del servidor decodificas el JWT con una clave que reside únicamente en el backend, y si el JWT es válido proseguir el flujo. Un JWT se desencripta a un objeto que puede contener muchos atributos, uno de ellos puede ser la llave para desencriptar lo que encriptaste con Sodium

Comment: La duda principalmente está en la seguridad del contenido de una sesión. Necesito que alguien que pueda acceder físicamente a la máquina no pueda conocer lo que guarda la base de datos.

Pero tengo que dejar una puerta a recuperar los datos (no quiero hacer un clon de mega).

La solución de JWT no me gusta, no quiero que la seguridad dependa de lo que hay en el cliente.